# Determine whether CSS requested the file

Tags: php

Is there a way to determine whether the file has been requested by CSS? Assuming that everything goes through a master file `index.php`.

Comment: You can add an url prefix like &type=css to the requested file and then check that in your php script.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you ever need to use the exact same URL for different types of requests?

Comment: I handle every request from my application. And special optimization routines are done for different requests. I might as well add special templates for different requests, like- CSS doesn't get served as a plain text, but served as editable that you can save and for that session you'll have your own custom CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this done, a pretty hacky way, but possible.

Basicly, the router (a PHP one) works with masks, and some files can only be accessed if the mask has been set.

When loading CSS file, I set the required mask, when loading the corresponding images I check for the mask and if it matches the required one, I load display the image. So, when looking at the rendered page it works, but when accessing the file directly, it does not.

Mask is a SESSION variable for now, that gets unset after file routing.

I will get a clean working example and update this answer with it sometime in future.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you append a get parameter to it like in

```
background:url('bg.jpg?myParam');
```

the requests browser makes from img tag and css definition do not differ.